# make a program reload an already opened file on file change

Tags: bash, ubuntu, reload

I need to play a `.swf` file then when the file is changed to reload the player with new content. Sadly, my program of choice does not do monitor files for changes. I came up with a bit convoluted solution:

```
sudo apt-get install incron gtk-gnash
echo "my_username" | sudo tee -a /etc/incron.allow # allow my_username to run incron
incrontab -e
```

add the following to incrontab:

```
/home/my_username/path/myfile.swf IN_MODIFY /home/my_username/path/run.sh
```

and the `run.sh` contains: ( also `chmod 700 run.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh
killall gtk-gnash
gtk-gnash /home/my_username/path/myfile.swf
```

As you can see this is far from elegant. How else could I go about this?

This is on Ubuntu 12.04 if that matters for you. This is a duplicate of my own [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201708/swf-player-aware-of-file-changes/202040) on askubuntu

**EDIT:** clarification, I chose to use gtk-gnash, a standalone player, this is not required, a web browser would do too but seems not necessary

Comment: What about launching your existing SWF inside a SWF wrapper that *does* do periodic checks for updates, and if it sees one, reloads the child SWF?  Are you in a position to generate SWFs, or does your solution have to be server based?  (What about a JavaScript handler that does what I described with the SWF wrapper?)  The thing is, it's *much* easier for a client to poll looking for changes, than for the server to push something to a client that has already downloaded the SWF and closed the connection.

Comment: I am generating SWFs myself in another bash script and then replacing an already playing swf. This happens whenever new content is available. This is all done locally and the output SWF played on a screen in some hallway. If I understand you correctly JS wrapper would have to be a script from within a browser, I guess such JS could not be made aware of disk changes, only reload periodically, this is a slight performance issue). Also, I'm not very skilled in JS and would like to remain so ;) (I see it as an unnecessary complication, there must be a simpler solution).

Comment: So you're launching this SWF in a standalone player?  That would have been useful information to start with.  If this is the case, you can simply run the player in a loop, then have a separate process watching for changes, killing the player if it sees a change.  If this sounds right to you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, I prefer a standalone one (like gnash is), added clarification now. I have started out with a bash script doing what you described: `while [ 1 ]; do gtk-gnash main.swf ; done &` but this seems not much different to what I posted in question, it's just that I replaced a script watching for changes with incron but yes, post your answer by all means, I'm sure it'll be informative, not only to me. I'm still wondering whether there is some other approach though. Thanks ghoti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the job of a [File Alteration Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor).

First off, your existing "incrontab" solution is a good starting point, given that you're launching things from shell.  The fact that incrontab is an [inotify(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html)-based solution is a huge plus.  It means that you aren't polling, which saves CPU.

You're asking for shell and system-level solutions, and I'm not a Flash programmer, so I'll stick to your question, though I think a better solution would be to create a Flash "wrapper" that perhaps uses an AS3 Loader class to suck in your existing SWF and receive notifications from something launched by incrontab.  Flash programming is way out of scope for this answer, though it might provide a more elegant solution.

So...

Your current method consists of a launch script that first kills any existing `gtk-gnash` process then runs a new one.  It gets relaunched from scratch when incrontab sees a change to the file.  That's a viable solution if you trust that your flash application will never crash and quit, and if you always have perfect timing.  One problem with it is that you've got an unknown delay between the death of one process and the start of the next.  Your `killall` sends a signal, which `gtk-gnash` may respond to immediately, or after a pause.  With a short pause, you might find yourself launching the SWF before the old one is fully gone.  With a longer pause, you may briefly show your desktop.

A better solution might be simply to launch the SWF within a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    date '+[%Y-%m-%d %T] myfile.swf relaunched' >> /var/log/swf.log
    gtk-gnash /home/my_username/path/myfile.swf
done
```

Then have incrontab merely kill the existing process:

```
/home/my_username/path/myfile.swf IN_MODIFY killall gtk-gnash
```

By separating the killall from the launch, you make sure that the new instance of gtk-gnash does not start until the old one has actually quit and returned control to the shell script wrapping it.

Of course, instead of using incrontab, you could alternatively install the `inotify-tools` package and leave a loop running:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify /home/my_username/path/myfile.swf; do
    killall gtk-gnash
done
```

Same syscalls, same effect, different front-end.

If you want to be über-careful about what process you're killing, you can also store the pid of gtk-gnash in a temporary file.  Here's another take on the flash player wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    date '+[%Y-%m-%d %T] myfile.swf relaunched' >> /var/log/swf.log
    gtk-gnash /home/my_username/path/myfile.swf &
    echo $! > /var/run/gtk-gnash.pid
    wait
done
```

And the incrontab line:

```
/home/my_username/path/myfile.swf IN_MODIFY xargs kill < /var/run/gtk-gnash.pid
```

Another strategy you might employ to reduce the *visible* effect of the kill/restart, is to take a screenshot of myfile.swf while it is running with minimal or no content, then use that as the desktop wallpaper on the player.  (Or equivalent.  I don't know how you're set up.)  I did something similar for a digital signage solution I set up a few years ago -- from time to time we needed to kill and restart a standalone player, so we made just the "frame" of the first page that shows up.  When we killed the flashplayer process, the system "seemed" to reset with no content in its boxes ... and then, a second later, content would show up.  (Yes, it's a hack.)

One other tip: I've always found Adobe's stand-alone Flash player ("Projector") to be more reliable and more compatible than gtk-gnash. You can find Adobe's stand-alone player at the [Adobe Support Centre Download Page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), which is different from their standard Flash Player download page.

Comment: thank you, this is a thorough answer, also thank you for the Projector tip, sadly, Adobe being Adobe, they don't support command line well (at all?), not even --fullscreen argument and I'd need another workaround (easy, but still), gnash will have to suffice

Comment: The Fullscreen functionality is controlled within Flash.  In your main timeline, include the following in the first frame: ` fscommand("fullscreen", "true");`.  This worked for me in AS2.  In AS3, I believe you would use the Stage class’s displayState property: `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`  More info is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html).

Comment: I create the swf by concatenating a bunch of pdfs using pdf2swf, so it's a different story

Comment: You can take the SWF you create, then use `swfc` and `swfcombine` to wrap it in another SWF that includes the fullscreen command.  Examples are at [Swfc_Code_Snippets](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfc_Code_Snippets).

Comment: I just tested this with Gnash.  I'm able to make a `.sc` file that includes another swf with `loadMovie()` then runs `Stage["displayState"]="fullScreen";` to switch to full screen.  I compile the file using `swfc`.  The "inclusion" is done at runtime, so it can be replaced and the full-screen viewer re-run.  I suspect it would also be possible to signal the viewer to reload the included file somehow, but that's out of scope for now.  This also works with the Flash projector on Mac OSX - haven't tested it in Linux.